# What could be the point in sending the length of the file name in this assignment?

Tags: sockets, tcp, ftp, network-programming, short

So I have to implement file transfer using socket programming (TCP), and one of the commands is to delete a file. We were asked to do it in the following way:

DELF:

1. Client sends operation (DELF) to delete a file from the server. Note: you can create a test file called "delete.txt" with random strings in the server directory to test the DELF operation.
2. Client sends the length of the file name (short int) followed by the file name (character string).
3. Server receives the above information, decodes file name size and file name, and checks if the file to be deleted exists or not.

But I can't seem to find a reason for sending the length of the file name? Why can't you just send the file name and find its length using String.length? The idea that the length of the file name (as short int) is sent with the file name is repeated constantly. But why?

Comment: I believe that you are thinking WAY to much about the assignment. Why not ask the person that wrote the assignment? Yes, I agree, why not send the file and derive the length. Doing this alternative could be part of a future assignment, but for now, the task is simply a redundant way even it might be "silly".

Comment: Because I need to include the file name size should I instead use dataoutputstream writeUTF for the name and writeShort for name size?

Comment: @SonyaArnolds Actually `writeUTF()` is already a valid solution to the question all by itself, as it already sends the length in 16 bits ahead of the data. Note that you have to use `DataInputStream.readUTF()` at the other end to read it.

Answer (score -1):

I see two reasons : to make the exercise more complicated (you will have to find by yourself that you need a separator character between the length and the name otherwise.. just think of a file which is named with numbers only) ; and the second reason is to secure the process in case the length and the file name lengths don't match for any reason (bugged client calling your program, bad support of international characters,..)

Comment: Why can't I just have a menu that goes 'Enter command' -> upload, 'enter filename' -> filename, to get the filename on one line?

Comment: You can, and it would work. But that's not the problem your teacher is asking you to solve. When I'm saying it can be related to security, I mean that, for example, the client sends UTF-8 and the server reads ASCII, the file names can be different, and their length too.

Answer (score -1):

Because otherwise you don't know where it ends, so the server doesn't know where the next command from the client begins.

Comment: Why can't I just have a menu that goes 'Enter command' -> upload, 'enter filename' -> filename, to get the filename on one line?

Comment: Your question was about what you are being told to send on the wire, and I've answered it. I don't know what the menu has to do with it.

Comment: It ends with a carriage return.

Comment: @EugèneAdell What ends with a  carriage return? Is that remark addressed to me? Why?

Comment: @EJP Yes. The user input needs to end with a carriage return or anything else that means that it's time to send the DELF command to the server. Your answer said we don't know where it ends, but we know because we add this carriage return at the end, like all level 7 protocols do to send their commands (for the protocols I know such FTP, HTTP,..). Otherwise, it means each byte is sent one by one, and just think that a file name can be made of numbers only, it looks impossible to solve.

Comment: @EugèneAdell There is nothing in the question about sending a carriage return. The instruction was to send a *length word*, and the question was why. Sending a carriage return is an alternative solution, but it isn't what the question is about. To quote your own comment: 'that's not the problem your teacher is asking you to solve'. Keep it relevant.